Getting exactly $n$ pizzas and $n$ ice creams
At each period in time, a person receives either an ice cream or a pizza, the probability being equal, i.e. $1/2$: Consider $2n$ time periods. What is the probability he received the same amount of pizzas and ice creams ?.

I assume the sample space is of size $2^{2n}$, as we have $2n$ time periods, and at each we have exactly $2$ options.
Out of which, I would like to consider $2n$ options and take $n$ from them to be ice creams, the other $n$ would, by default, be pizzas.
Therefore, the probability is:
$$
{\left(2n\right)!/\left(2\, n!\right) \over 2^{2n}} = 
{\left(2n\right)! \over 2^{n + 1}\, n!}
$$
Is my solution correct ?.
I'm having doubts, as $\left(2n\right)!/\left(2\, n!\right)$ is the number of options to consider $n$ pizzas and $n$ ice creams when it is forbidden to repeat an item and the order of items has no meaning, yet $2^{2n}$ is exactly the opposite - the order matters and it is allowed to have the same item repeat itself.

As funny as it may seem to ask, I would appreciate a clarification as to why my solution is correct/incorrect ( even if it is correct ).

$2(n!)$ does not accurately describe the condition that the order of the ice creams and the order of the pizzas doesn't matter.
I agree that if all $n$ pizzas and $n$ ice creams are distinguishable from each other, there are $(2n)!$ ways to order them. However there are $n!$ ways to order the pizzas between them and $n!$ ways to order the ice creams between them that result in the same configuration. So in fact there are not $2(n!)$ ways to reorder into the same configuration, but $n! \times n! = (n!)^2$ ways (you multiply independent choices instead of adding them the way you did).
Thus the probability to receive the same amount of pizzas and ice creams is $\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}$.
Another way to view it: choosing a way to receive the same amount of pizzas and ice creams is equivalent to choosing $n$ out of the $2n$ time periods where we receive a pizza (we would thus receive ice cream on the time periods that weren't chosen).
There are thus $\binom{2n}{n}$ (also written $2nCn$) equally likely ways to receive the same amount of pizzas and ice creams. The probability is thus $\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}$, exactly the same answer as above.

You must assume that the different periods correspond to independent events.
Then the number of pizzas in $2n$ time periods is a binomial random variable with parameters $2n$ and $1/2$, and the probability that it is $n$ is
$${2n \choose n} 2^{-2n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 2^{2n}}$$
The ${2n \choose n}$ (note that it is not $\frac{(2n)!}{2n!}$) is because there are that many ways to choose which $n$ of the $2n$ time periods give you pizza, the $2^{-2n}$ is because that is the probability of any one sequence of pizzas and ice creams.

Thank you.  It is certainly my mistake about ${2n \choose n}$. I understand your approach by considering it as a binomial random variable.  Yet, what of $\frac{{2n \choose n}}{2^{2n}}$? Wouldn't this lead to a different answer?

Never mind, I think it is the same expression.

Whenever you can, you should look at a problem, and see if it matches a familiar class of problem(s)
This problem is exactly equivalent to tossing a fair coin $2n$ times, and finding the probability of getting an equal # of heads and tails, thus
$$Pr = \dfrac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}$$
Trying to further "simplify" it into factorials only obscures the clarity !

“Familiar” for me is a spin.: $\pm 1$. Look for  total spin zero.

$$
{1 \over 2^{2n}}\left[z^{0}\right]\
\overbrace{\left(z + {1 \over z}\right)^{2n}}
^{\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose k}z^{2n - 2k}} = \color{#44f}{{2n \choose n} \over 2^{2n}}
$$
